# SSD upgrade for mid 2012 MBP

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, ssd

I recently started getting performance issues with my MBP while running apps like Xcode and Eclipse. A quick diagnostic of the system showed that it thrashed over 458k times.

```
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000b   095   095   062    Pre-fail  Always       -       458757
```

I just ordered a SSD to replace the HDD, will this help solve the problem, and also how do I get OSX back onto the computer if I replace the HDD and the new SSD is empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put it in an external caddy, USB etc, then use something like [Carbon Copy Cloner](http://bombich.com/features) to duplicate it.

It will then be bootable when you swap.

Answer (score 1):

This RAW value means nothing to you disregard it.
[Here is on understanding SMART attributes](http://lime-technology.com/wiki/index.php/Understanding_SMART_Reports#Table_of_attributes).

From there:

> PLEASE completely ignore the RAW_VALUE number! Only Seagates report
>   the raw value, which yes, does appear to be the number of raw read
>   errors, but should be ignored, completely. All other drives have raw
>   read errors too, but do not report them, leaving this value as zero
>   only. To repeat, Seagates are not worse than other drives because they
>   appear to have raw read errors, rather they are the only one to report
>   the number. I suspect that others do not report the number to avoid a
>   lot of confusion, and questions for their tech support people. Seagate
>   leaves those of us who provide tech support the job of answering the
>   constant questions about this number. Hopefully now that you
>   understand this, you will never bother a kind IT person with questions
>   about the Raw_Read_Error_Rate RAW_VALUE again?

Regarding getting OS X on computer you can either clone your existing install (like mentioned before), [start with Internet Recovery](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT4718) (pressing <kbd>cmd</kbd> + r) or prepare bootable USB key with installer with [Diskmaker X](http://liondiskmaker.com) utility or [manually](http://osxdaily.com/2014/10/18/clean-install-os-x-yosemite/)

System on SSD for sure be a lot faster than on HDD